# Why is my ender portal not working?

Tags: technical-issues

So I made an end portal in Minecraft and I did everything I needed to but it still didn't work I tried looking it up but it just gave me the wrong so-called "Answers" and they aren't even really answers! The stars didn't show up (they look like stars)

Comment: Would you, at least, add what version of Minecraft you are playing?

Comment: And maybe add a screenshot of your portal, describe what "everything I needed to" entails, and link to the "answers" you found?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_portal):

> In Creative mode, the player can construct an end portal by placing 12 end portal blocks in a ring enclosing an open 3×3 square and placing an eye of ender in each one. In order to activate, **the end portal frames must be oriented correctly**; the front face of each portal block must be pointed inward toward the 3×3 portal area. This can be achieved by the player standing in the center of the portal area and rotating to place the frames in a ring around them.

[image]

A possible solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might not of worked because you have not place the frames facing the inside of the portal, it will only work if you do it in that way

Comment: This is essentially my same answer.